# What happens for the SCR if I connect gate with ground when it is turned on?

Tags: scr

When I connected a silicon control rectifier by applying positive voltage in anode and negative voltage in cathode, after that I triggered the gate by pulse voltage and it connected, after that I want to connect gate with ground and I want to know what happened.

Comment: Have you read: https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/electronic_components/scr/how-does-thyristor-work-operation.php  ? Realize that an SCR is also called "thyristor" and that it is either in an **on** state or an **off** state (somewhat simplified but good enough for now). Then note this sentence at the bottom of the page: *Once switched on, the thyristor can only be turned off by removing the supply voltage.*

Comment: It really depends on what you refer to as ground and more specifically what the Cathode potential is.

Comment: yes I read it ,
I connected this circuit in Proteus 8 Professional to show what happens 
I showed that when voltage is very large SCR would be turn on without triggering voltage on gate , I think that it happens , because the applying voltage larger than VB for SCR 
and when voltage is small , don't turn on without triggering voltage and when I connected gate with ground SCR became turn off , but I don't know why

Comment: Beware of high slewrates on the anode of the SCR. These cause (via I = C * dV/dT) large transient currents inside the SCR, and may be adequate to trigger the SCR into positive-feedback and thus into permanent SCR behavior (at least until the current thru the SCR is taken to zero)

Comment: Think of it as cattle in a fenced in field with a gate.  You unlatch the gate, and cattle will pour through.  The gate will remain unlatched until the cows stop coming through, at which point the gate closes and relatches, until it is opened again by unlatching it.

Answer (score 1):

If the SCR is passing sufficient current (latching current or greater) then no matter what you do with the gate, the device will continue to be "latched": -

[image]

Image from [Wireless World](http://www.rfwireless-world.com/Terminology/SCR-firing-or-SCR-triggering.html). However, if the current is taken to below the "hold current" value, the SCR will unlatch and the gate (if desired) can be used to re-activate it.

Answer (score 1):

If you connect the gate to the cathode directly, or apply a negative voltage, and current above the holding current is flowing from anode to cathode, it **may** commutate (turn off), especially if the anode current is close to the holding current, however this behavior is not guaranteed.

In GTO (Gate Turn-Off) devices, the behavior is guaranteed (and the design is different to make behavior turn-off reliable and more sensitive).

See the accepted answer [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/265690/scr-gate-to-negative) for the difference in construction.

If you consider the two-transistor model of the SCR, it looks like it should **always** turn off, however that model does not exactly correspond to reality (image from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon_controlled_rectifier).

[image]

Comment: I think that i have answer , when I apply voltage between anode and cathode make (VAK ) >(VB) so the SCR will turn on without triggering voltage from gate to turn on,so when i connect gate with ground some current will pass through gate but the current between anode and cathode will not decrease about current holding

Comment: If one connects gate and cathode directly when the SCR is on, most likely the gate current is too high and the gate is destroyed.

Comment: @Janka  No. Maybe you're thinking of gate-to-anode?

Comment: But when the voltage between anode and cathode is smaller than VB , so the SCR need triggering voltage from gate to turn on and after that when i connect gate with ground , the current will pass through gate to ground make the current between anode and cathode decrease from current holding ,but if the current doesn't decrease from current holding the SCR will still turn on 
my description is correct or no , please answer .

Comment: @EslamHaSsanUWk The SCR will *stay* on.. yes that sounds essentially correct.

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany 
so we can say anything happens in the SCR to change it from turn on to turn off depend on current holding

Comment: The gate-cathode connection shunts away some of the feedback current, and may reduce the positive feedback enough to make it turn off.

Comment: can you explain more about it